# Has the algorithm for "Interesting" questions changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, interesting-page

In the last couple of days I've noticed that the homepage (when logged in), with its default filter of "Interesting" has gone from being consistently 90% questions containing one or more of my Watched Tags, to maybe 10%.

Has anything changed recently regarding these filters? Or is everyone in the web development world just having a very productive, question-free, few days?

Comment: Similar question on the lowly Meta site: *[Has the formula for “interesting” questions recently changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389861)*

Comment: Thanks for reporting, see bug on MSO linked above for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a caching bug in the way the list was generated; a fix has [just been rolled out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389892/2157772).