# Stack Overflow - Home - Interesting tab: Showing almost no yellow card (interesting) questions

Tags: bug, tags, questions, interesting-page

I am a web developer who is used to navigating the Interesting tab in the Home page of *Stack Overflow* to find fresh new questions that use the tags that I configured in my profile (JS, HTML, CSS, ReactJS, regex, etc...).

Usually, this tab shows an abundance of yellow card questions, so questions that have at least one of the tags that I am intersted in. However, today, I am seeing almost no such cards and the questions I get in the page have random tags, and even some of them are really old (but with fresh answers).

[image]

This behavior seems odd to me and it's disrupting. I am not sure if it's a bug or something the *Stack Overflow* developers are experimenting with.

Does anybody have a clue what's happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has the algorithm for "Interesting" questions changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333899/has-the-algorithm-for-interesting-questions-changed) it's been like this all day